# Arrow open_dataset() error: CSV conversion error to int64: invalid value '' despite assigning the column as utf8 in schema()

Tags: r, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I tried loading multiple csvs which is from a larger mother dataset split into 4 CSVs.

```
hh<-open_dataset(
  sources="location in local folder",
  format="csv",
  skip_rows = 1,
  schema=schema(
    REG= int64(),
    PRV= int64(),
    MUN= int64(),
    BGY= int64(),
    EA= int64(),
    BSN= int64(),
    HUSN= int64(),
    HSN= int64(),
    FTYPE= utf8(),
    MODE= utf8(),
    LNRES= int64(),
    B1= int64(),
    B2= int64(),
    B3= int64(),
    B4= int64(),
    B5= int64(),
    B6= int64(),
    B7= int64(),
    B8= int64(),
    D1= int64(),
    H1= int64(),
    H2= int64(),
    H3A= int64(),
    H3B= int64(),
    H3C= int64(),
    H3D= int64(),
    H3E= int64(),
    H3F= int64(),
    H4= int64(),
    H5= int64(),
    H6= int64(),
    H7= int64(),
    H8= int64(),
    H9= int64(),
    H10= int64(),
    H11A= int64(),
    H11B= int64(),
    H11C= int64(),
    H11D= int64(),
    H12A= int64(),
    H12B= int64(),
    H12C= int64(),
    H12D= int64(),
    H12E= int64(),
    H13= int64(),
    H14= int64(),
    H15A= int64(),
    H15B= int64(),
    H15C= int64(),
    H15D= int64(),
    H15E= int64(),
    H15F= int64(),
    H15G= int64(),
    H15H= int64(),
    H15I= int64(),
    H15J= int64(),
    H15K= int64(),
    H15L= int64(),
    H15M= int64(),
    H15N= int64(),
    H15O= int64(),
    H15P= int64(),
    H15Q= int64(),
    H15R= int64(),
    H15S= int64(),
    H16A= int64(),
    H16B= int64(),
    H16C= int64(),
    H16D= int64(),
    H17A= int64(),
    H17B= int64(),
    H17C= int64(),
    H17D= int64(),
    H17E= int64(),
    H17F= int64(),
    H17G= int64(),
    H17H= int64(),
    H14RECODE= int64(),
    BSN_1ST= int64(),
    HUSN_1ST= int64(),
    HSN_1ST= int64()
  )
)
```

Then I wanted to turn into parquet following Hadley Wickham's tutorial (https://r4ds.hadley.nz/arrow.html). The code is

```
pq_path1<-"local folder location"
hh %>% write_dataset(path = pq_path1, format = "parquet")
```

But I always receive an error message that reads:

> Invalid: In CSV column #10: Row #1056: CSV conversion error to int64: invalid value ''

Despite the fact that the column # 10 is written like this in the schema.

```
MODE= utf8(),
```

I am also trying to create a an arrow dataset (still learning the arrow jargon) which has fewer columns with either lines of code

```
hh<-hh %>% select(LNRES, REG, PRV, MUN, BGY, EA, BSN, HUSN, HSN, H6, starts_with("H16"), B3, B4,H6,H9,H10, starts_with("H15") )

hh<-hh |> select(LNRES, REG, PRV, MUN, BGY, EA, BSN, HUSN, HSN, H6, starts_with("H16"), B3, B4,H6,H9,H10, starts_with("H15") )
```

Error message is

> CSV conversion error to int64: invalid value ''

R also output a list in the global environment.

Comment: Welcome to SO, M.A.! This is going to be very difficult to answer without sample data. Are you able to add a few rows of your underlying file to a code block?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.